# Process ColdFusion Form with Component

Tags: forms, function, methods, coldfusion, cfc

When a Coldfusion form calls a cfc as the action, is it possible for the browser to stay on the form page or does the component function have to reroute it back to the form page?

```
<cfform name="crops" action="cfc/stages.cfc?method=update" method="post">
```

Once the form above is posted, it stays on the component page rather than rerouting back to the form page.

Comment: You need to look into using AJAX to submit the form. You really can't submit a form the way you mentioned directly to a CFC. Oh, and stop using `cfform` it will be more trouble than it is worth. Use a plain old HTML form.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted for a similar question. It should get you started with the form HTML, JavaScript to post the data via Ajax and a simple CFC function to verify that it received the data correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461078/post-parameters-from-ajax-request-undefined-in-form-scope-in-coldfusion/11472873#11472873

Comment: Adrian, I want to thank you.  I revisited your post today.  Your sample code in the link you provided was helpful.  I'm still absorbing jquery and js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish what you appear to want is to submit the form to the page containing it.  No ajax required.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "aKnownFormField")>
code to process form
can use create object to access cfc code if you want
</cfif>
<form action="thePageIAmOn.cfm" method="post">
<input name="aKnownFormField" type = "text">
more form fields
</form>
```