# JQUERY AJAX - function success returns "UNDEFINED" with CFC query

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a problem with implementing AJAX in my form for linking drop down lists. I use ColdFusion (CFC file) for retrieving results from a query. The function is working and I retrieve the results in JSON format:

```
[ { "ID" : "APEX",
    "VALUE" : "Apex (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "AVI",
    "VALUE" : "Plane (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "TRAIN 1",
    "VALUE" : "Train 1st class"
  },
  { "ID" : "VOIT",
    "VALUE" : "Car"
  },
  { "ID" : "ZERO",
    "VALUE" : "Cost 0 (not defined)"
  }
]
```

I do not know if this JSON is correct in order to be used in the jquery script.

In the JQUERY script the `success` function doesn't retrieve these results and `console.log(result)` displays "undefined". If I try to do `console.log(result.length)`, the error is displayed.

In Firebug I can see that the query has been done and the response is the JSON below.

My JQuery script in my CFM file:

```
$().ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type:   'GET',
        url:    'transport.cfc',
        data: {
            method:     'getTransports',
            CITY_TO:    'LUX',
            CITY_FROM:  'UWP'
        },
        dataType:       'json',
        contentType:    'application/json',

        success: function(result) {
            var select = $("##transp");
            select.empty();
            select.append(
                new Option('Select transport', '-1')
            );
            console.log(result) // displays "undifined"

            /* GENERATES BUG
            $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                select.append(
                    new Option(item.ID, item.VALUE)
                );
            });*/
        },

        error: function(xhr, message) {
            alert('ajax request failed');
            console.log(xhr, message);
        }
     });
});
```

I am using Jquery version 1.1.2. I tried to use the last version, but the result is the same. I also tried the following solution proposed on a forum: "replace json by jsonp". By doing that, the results are displayed in the console, thanks to `console.log(result)`, but the loop `each` is not ok and the error 'ajax request failed' appears

I do not know how to solve the problem, can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: In firebug I can see that the XHR query returns corrects results but in the headers it's written : "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8". It should be 'application/json' ? Thus I do not think that the JSON format is not correct

Comment: If the success argument `result` is `undefined`, the request didn't return valid JSON. Double check the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a comprehensive answer to [using Ajax with CFC functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11472873/11047). I think all you're missing is the `returnformat` of the function.

The Ajax code I posted:

```
$.ajax({
    async : true,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : 'test.cfc?method=testing&returnformat=json',
    data : {
        a : $('#a').val(),
        b : $('#b').val()
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
        $('#data').val(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

You're passing the method name in the `data` packet. Try adding the `returnformat` there as well:

```
url: 'transport.cfc',
data: {
    method:     'getTransports',
    returnformat:  'json',
    CITY_TO:    'LUX',
    CITY_FROM:  'UWP'
},
```

This should ensure that the content returned from the function has the correct `content-type`.